# The Scenario Outlines args whether support variables?

Tags: cucumber

I walked through the [Scenario Outlines Wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines), but I have some questions about it:

1, For example, as the below shows, the data table values whether support the variables?

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start               | eat | left |
    |  <%= cb.prefix %>   |  5  |  7   |
    |  <%= cb.prefix %>   |  5  |  15  |
```

2, The below format whether right? Or I must create a new variable to replace the last `<left>`? In other words, how to re-use these variables, `<start>`, `<eat>`, `<left>`?

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers
  And there are <left> cucumbers left

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left | left |
    |  12   |  5  |  7   |  7   |
    |  20   |  5  |  15  |   7  |
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the first case,** no, unfortunately variables are not part of the spec inside of feature files.

A way to work around this, I've found, is storing the information you need in an object, map:

```
starts = {prefix1: 12, prefix2: 20}
```

Using this in your step definition will mean that you can do this:

```
Given "there are $prefix cucumbers" do |prefix|
   prefix = starts[prefix]

   # Do stuff with the prefix
end
```

This done right means that the feature file maintains readability, but you can still do more with it. In the past I've stored URL's in this way, made an alias for them in the map, and used this in my step definitions.

**In the second case,** your first method is the way that you would go about this.

If you have the need to input the same parameter twice, one column in the examples table will do to input that information. If you are looking to change the data within that column, however, that will be where you use a new parameter name.

```
Scenario: I eat nothing
   Given I have <number_of_apples> apples
   When I eat 0 of them
   Then I should have <number_of_apples> left

Examples:
  | number_of_apples |
  | 5                |
  | 12               |
```

**Edit**

In the comments, asked the question *"In a Scenario, I have to repeat many steps just due to a different args in one of the steps, so, how to improve this case?"*

I'd have a look into the data tables functionality in that case.

An example in the feature file would look like this:

```
Given I have an amount of the following fruits:
  | apples  |
  | oranges |
When I eat some apples
Then I should have a lesser amount of apples
But I should have the same amount of oranges
```

The code would look like this:

```
Given "I have an amount of the following fruits:" do |table|
   data = table.raw
   # do stuff with the data
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! For the first case, the variables got from its previous step, so I could not get them in advance. :(

Comment: @JianZhang So your scenario has a couple of Givens? If that's the case, include the setting up of the variable "starts" in more of a global context, or alternatively write them to a file that you can access in your second step. However, it could be that you may be trying to make the scenario more readable after they have run, which would mean that you might not know the number you are starting with. If this is the case, change the wording, Given I have an amount of apples", "When I eat some", "Then I should have the correct amount of apples left"

Comment: Many thanks! I will have a try! Another question: In a scenario, I have to repeat many steps just due to a different args in one of the steps, so, how to improve this case? I do not want to add many lines for these repeat steps, they look ugly. :(

Comment: See my edit, it should give you the information you need